# What if sizeof(T) is larger than chunk size in std::deque<T>?

Tags: c++, stl

As far as I know, almost all the std::deque implementation in C++ is based on a list of fixed chunks.
Since the chunk is fixed size, I'm thinking what if sizeof(T) is larger than the chunk size? Will one element cross two chunks in this case?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that, in this context, "chunk is fixed size" means "the number of Ts in each chunk is fixed". An element cannot "cross two chunks in this case", this is impossible in C++.

Comment: The "chunks" are thing like a fixed sized array or `T` or a `std::vector<T>`.  You can't have a chunk smaller then the element type because of that.

Comment: Yes.  It's a _distinct_ fixed size for every type `T`, and that size is never less than `sizeof(T)`

Comment: Note that as the number of elements in a "chunk" gets smaller, a `deque` looks more and more like a `list`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: In Visual Studio, the number of Ts in each chunk is not fixed :( In Visual Studio, the number of Ts per chunk is something like `max(1, 4019/sizeof(T))`

Answer (score 3):

In libc++, the "chunk size" for a `deque<T>` is either `16*sizeof(T)` or `4096` bytes, whichever is larger.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, let's have a look at a concrete example from libstdc++. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/libstdc++/api/a01620_source.html#l00680) is a function that allocates memory for the said nodes:

```
template <typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
void _Deque_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_initialize_map(size_t __num_elements) {
  const size_t __num_nodes =
      (__num_elements / __deque_buf_size(sizeof(_Tp)) + 1);
  // ...
```

As you can see, it calls `__deque_buf_size`, which is defined on line 88 like so:

```
GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR inline size_t __deque_buf_size(size_t __size) {
  return (__size < _GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE
              ? size_t(_GLIBCXX_DEQUE_BUF_SIZE / __size)
              : size_t(1));
}
```

So, if the element is smaller than a predefined buffer size, the result is however many elements of that type would fit in that predefined size, otherwise the result is 1. That means our chunks are at least as large as a predefined buffer size, and possibly larger, if needed.